# Traits, helper service or inheritance for eliminating repetitive code in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, traits

I'm trying to clean up an older Symfony2 project where most of the code is inside controllers. Long, repetitive blocks of code in a controller is not optimal, it makes debugging & development very tedious and error-prone.

There are plenty of things I can easily clean up and move into services, as those blocks of code provide some sort of reusable functionality. I get that any well-defined task should live in a service, and controllers should just be "wiring".

But no matter where I move the code, there are always small repetitive blocks cluttering everything up. Things like initialization/transformation/parsing/filtering patterns for example, which are used extensively in our application.

Take for example the data "kneading" needed for the creation of a DataTable:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller {

    public function indexAction() {

        $data = array(/* some data */);

        $encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
        $normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
        $datatable = $this->get('datatables.orders');
        $datatable->buildDatatableView();
        $datatable->setData($serializer->serialize($data, 'json'));

        return array('datatable'=>$datatable);
    }
}
```

That's a very common, but also very verbose pattern. Our developers tend to store dozens of these kinds of little patterns in text files on their own computers, and often copy/paste them into controllers.

If I try to think of solutions to make the code a bit more concise (and DRY), there are multiple options.

- I could filter duplicate patterns out of all actions and dump them into private functions. I've done this in some locations to clear things up a bit, but it's a bad solution that is localized to each controller.
- I could create one or more generalized "helper" classes with all these code snippets, and `use` them whenever I need them in a service or controller, containing all kinds of parsing/checking/filtering/building functions. It would probably turn into a garbage collection of tiny unrelated methods though.
- I could create one or more abstract classes with properties/methods used in many services/controllers, and inherit from that. Feels hacky, especially if I need to sandwich it in between a user defined controller and the Symfony framework controller class.
- I could define traits for these data-transformation functions, and use those wherever applicable. People often claim that PHP traits are almost always bad. However, traits seem like the least abusive and most concise option to me.

Consider this:

Bundle/Traits/TableTrait.php

```
Trait TableTrait {
    function serialize($data, $format){
        $encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
        $normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
        return $serializer->serialize($data, $format);
    }

    function buildTable($table, $data){
        $datatable = $table;
        $datatable->buildDatatableView();
        $datatable->setData($this->serialize($data, 'json'));
    }
}
```

Bundle/Controller/SomeController.php

```
class DefaultController extends Controller {

    use \Bundle\Traits\TableTrait;

    public function indexAction() {

        $data = array(/* some data */);
        $datatable = $this->buildTable($this->get('datatables.orders'),$data);

        return array('datatable'=>$datatable);
    }
}
```

That reduces 6 lines of boilerplate to 1.

Are traits a bad solution for this? 
If so, which options would be better?

Comment: This seems like a great use of the [AppBundle\Utils](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/tree/master/src/AppBundle/Utils) namespace. I don't know that a `trait` makes any more sense than a set of well-defined utility classes; you're using `use` regardless, and whether these are "traits" or not is debatable. What keeps your traits from turning into a garbage collection of unrelated functionality as well?

Comment: Completely true. I somehow associate traits with smaller, less tightly related functions... A service is something big in my mind, like a post office (in symfony, handling all email for example) while a trait would define the fact that a street needs a postbox (initialisation of the mail service in another controller or service). That works nicely as a metaphor, but I don't know if there's any practical logic/truth behind that assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at moving some things into services.  For example:

```
$serializer = $this->get('json.getset.serializer');
```

And maybe make a data table factory service

```
$dataTable = $this->get('datatable.orders.factory')->create($data);
```

You could even go one step further, define your controllers as services then inject the needed dependencies.  So you would end up with:

```
$dataTable = $this->dataTableFactory->create($data);
```